# Is there a new URI for opening the XAMPP Security console on xampp 7.0.2-1?

Tags: xampp

Is there a new URI for opening the XAMPP Security console on xampp 7.0.2-1?

I use the URI `http://localhost/security/` and `http://localhost/security/index.php` but it doesn't work, I always get

> error 404. "Object not found!"

How can i access the XAMPP Security console on xampp 7.0.2-1?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a new security concept in use in XAMPP now. Also it seems that it's not documented for some reason. XAMPP versions 5.6.11+ do install by default with such security settings that only the XAMPP host computer is granted access to the XAMPP directory web pages and phpMyAdmin. So it's not wide open any more, although the documentation still seems to say so.

There's a good post on the issue here: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=71675

You can see if your installation is using the new security concept by accessing your phpmyadmin page (which would be http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ if accessed on the XAMPP host) from another computer. That page should now only load when accessed from the XAMPP host, from any other IP you should get 403 access forbidden.